# How to manage "Window" frame in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I am IPhone app developer.I am new to MAC apps development,right now I am working on Mac OSX application.Here I it consists two screens.In first screen there is a button(pic 1).On clicking on button it goes to next screen(Where the screen appears full screen,pic 2).There a textfield exists.if we enter correct text it goes back to previous screen.My issue is I am unable set the textfield frame in SecondView,its not getting set in centre.And while going back to previous screen button is missing(pic 3).Below pictures explains my problem clearly.

[image]

To open second window(MasterViewController) in full screen

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[appdelegate.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewCohntroller.view];
self.masterViewCohntroller.view.frame = ((NSView*)appdelegate.window.contentView).bounds;

 NSApplicationPresentationOptions presentationOptions =     (NSApplicationPresentationHideDock |NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar |
    NSApplicationPresentationDisableAppleMenu |
 NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching |
NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit |
NSApplicationPresentationDisableSessionTermination    |NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication);

NSDictionary *fullScreenOptions = @{NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: @(presentationOptions)};


[appdelegate.window.contentView enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:fullScreenOptions];
```

[image]

To to go back and exit full screen

```
  self.firstViewController=[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];

[appdelegate.window.contentView performSelector:@selector(exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];


[appdelegate.window.contentView addSubview:self.firstViewController.view];
self.firstViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)appdelegate.window.contentView).bounds;
```

[image]

Good suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you'll need to show some code, but I would have thought it was simpler to swap views within a constant (single) window, rather than messing about with multiple windows.

Comment: @trojanfoe hi ...please go through my edited question..

Comment: Ah cool, so it looks like you are changing the views within a single window.  OK, so are you using *Auto Layout* to provide the visible positioning of the UI-elements, or is it *Springs and Struts*?

Comment: I used single window and sub viewing the viewcontrollers. Iam not using autolayout.Is it not correct procedure? is there any sample which explains navigation between two views/windows.? @trojanfoe

Comment: I don't think the actual swapping is your problem, it's that you haven't told the UI-elements what happens when the size of their containing view changes.  You can check this in Xcode using the `Editor ⟶ Simulate Document`.

Comment: @trojanfoe As u said I set frame of UI elements to center as per the view size..I have been using that while loading the view in initwithnib name.But its not working too..

Comment: and there is no Simulate Document in Editor

Comment: What you set the initial position to isn't really important if the containing view's frame size will change.  You need to tell the UI-elements how they will move and/or resize when this happens, which you do with *Springs and Struts* (old way) or *Auto Layout* (new way).  When editing the NIB file there is the mentioned *Simulate Document* which lets you see the effect of such resizing during development.